# Find a compact neighborhood of $x$

Tags: general-topology

> Problem: Suppose $X$ is a locally compact and Hausdorff. Given $x \in X$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, find a compact neighborhood of $x$ which is contained  in $U$.

Attempt at a solution:

There exists a compact neighborhood $K$ of $x$. Since $K$ and $U$ are neighborhoods of $x$, $\exists$ a set $V$, open in $X$ s.t.
$x \in V \subseteq K \cap U$.

> Thm 1: If $A$ is a compact subset of a Hausdorff space $X$, and if $x \in X -A$, then there exists disjoint neighborhoods of $x$ and $A$. Therefore a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

By this theorem $K$ is closed in $X$, thus $V^c \cap K$ is closed in $X$.
If i am not wrong it is also true that $V^c \cap K$ is closed in $K$?

> Thm 2: A closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Hence $V^c \cap K$ is a compact subset of $K$.

It follows that $V^c \cap K$ is  also a compact subset of $X$.

---

I think i should use theorem 1 to finish it off but i am not sure on how to continue.

Comment: Assuming that there is no such compact neighborhood should give you a straightforward contradiction.

Comment: I suggest using the one-point compactification.

Comment: It is incorrect to be referring to compact neighborhoods. What  you are looking for is a nbhd $V$ of $x$ such that $\bar V$ is compact and $\bar V\subset U.$

Comment: @user254665 No, it is correct. Some people define a [neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29) of $x$ to be a set $N$ such that $x \in U \subset N$ for some open set $U$.

Comment: $David Heras...David and user those solution are probably even better but too advanced for me atm. E.g. I havent heard of the one-point compactification before but will look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Theorem 1, there exists disjoint open sets $O_1$, $O_2$ such that $x \in O_1$ and $K \cap U^c \subset O_2$. Set $N = K \cap O_2^c$. Then $N$ is compact by Theorem 2, and it is a neighborhood of $x$ because $K \cap O_1 \subset N$. Finally, $N$ is a subset of $U$ because $$N = K \cap O_2^c \subset K \cap (K \cap U^c)^c = K \cap U \subset U.$$